# settings gear icon is missing on vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons, settings

[image],settings gear icon is missing on vs code. How to get it back ?

tried to uninstall and reinstall vs code still its missing.

i want setting gear icon back on VS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to View → Appearance → Activity Bar and enable it:

[image: image showing how to navigate to activity bar setting]

Comment: thank you so much I got the gear icon back .